# About size of apps using RxAndroid

Tags: rx-java, rx-android, android-proguard

I am considering either adding a FSM to my app or building it on RxAndroid.

What really discourages me about RxAndroid, is the oversize required by RxJava itself.

So I would like to hear your experiences in size increase in the .apk using RxAndroid as a base framework including compression with ProGuard.

(If this is not the place to ask this question, kindly let me know which is the place since the github project is not the place either https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/issues/405)

Thanks

---

Update 10-12-2017: https://medium.com/googleplaydev/shrinking-apks-growing-installs-5d3fcba23ce2

Comment: RxAndroid have about 9k methods with nearly 2KB DEX size. This isn't really a big deal.

Comment: This means starting your app with 2MB+ of size. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @pellyadolfo there are a lot of subjects/observables/operators you probably won't use. ProGuard should remove them.
Just my specific use case, I added RxAndroid and the sample `Observable.just(...).map(...).subscribe(...);` and to my surprise it adds only about 7kb to the APK and 50kb to the installed app.